# MVC Anti-Forgery token not recognized

Tags: model-view-controller, server, http-post, adfs, antiforgerytoken

I'm struggling with an issue related to the anti forgery token.

I have "@Html.AntiForgeryToken();" in my cshtml file 
and " [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]" in my controller class

I verified that request body has "__RequestVerificationToken" hidden field and the cookie. However, the HTTP POST to the server is giving me the error:

*"The required anti-forgery form field "__RequestVerificationToken" is not present.* "

This same code works fine on other servers. This is not working on only one specific server.

Please provide suggestions on what to look for at the server level, that could be failing the anti-forgery token validation.